# SQL Getting the total or sum of a column

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

So here's the query that I currently have.

```
`SELECT war.id, inv.pro_id, inv.quantity
FROM L4_Warehouses war, L4_Inventories inv, L4_Employees emp, L4_Orders ord
WHERE inv.war_id = war.id AND
      war.id = emp.war_id AND
      emp.id = ord.emp_id AND
      ord.status = 'P'
ORDER BY inv.war_id, inv.pro_id;`
```

this query gives this table.

[image]

Now, what I want to get for the final result is to get the sum of those Quantities, example below

```
ID      PRO_ID      QUANTITY
1       100         18
1       101         6
1       110         6
```

Comment: Hint: `SUM(inv.quantity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SUM and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT war.id, inv.pro_id, SUM(inv.quantity)
FROM L4_Warehouses war, L4_Inventories inv, L4_Employees emp, L4_Orders ord
WHERE inv.war_id = war.id AND
      war.id = emp.war_id AND
      emp.id = ord.emp_id AND
      ord.status = 'P'
GROUP BY war.id, inv.pro_id
ORDER BY inv.war_id, inv.pro_id;
```

Comment: Yep, but I'm getting not a GROUP BY expression error.

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 10

Comment: My bad, my order by is incorrect. Thank you so much! Your solution worked!

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to help!